# Loading dynamically pages into div using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to load pages dynamically into a `div` using a `select`

My HTML code :

```
<div ng-app="App"  ng-controller="ProjectCtrl">
   <div>
      <select ng-model="selectedType" class="form-control" ng-change="showContent()" ng-options="type as type.text for type in types"></select>

   </div>

   <div>
        <div ng-include src='getView()'></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My JS code :

```
$scope.showContent= function() {
        $scope.getView = function() {
           return $scope.selectedType.value ;
        }
}
```

I got this error :

Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/ng/areq?p0=Ctrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

**P.S:** My views use angularJS too, and the idea is to get my page(View) from the `select`.
"Ctrl" is the control name of the loaded page

Comment: Are you missing a } for the $scope.getView function?

Comment: What's the `types` model look like?

Comment: Firstly have you considered using the Angular `$routeProvider` with the `ng-view` directive? If you are however set on this implementation or are using `ngview` for something else: Can you give your full controller, and why is the `getView()` function nested in another function?

Comment: I found a way to reproduce this probem : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/zBagAdBgJlslULlKnkvW?p=preview (When you select url1 the example is broken and you got this error : Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/ng/areq?p0=Ctrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like $scope.selectedType.value is returning null. Try `console.log`ging $scope.selectedType to see what you get. The function should return the full path.

**Update** 
After reviewing the plnk, it appears that you're trying to load an entire Angular app via ng-include. That's not what ng-include does, it just includes small templates. Here is the working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nq1AFBaamW3xycSa98uw?p=preview)

Comment: I tried already console.log($scope.selectedType.value) and I have the good name of my page! Thanks btw

Comment: you need more than the name, you need the actual path.

Comment: I think I need to load the controller too for the new page loaded! For this reason I get this error

Comment: You do not need another controller.

Comment: I found a way to reproduce this probem : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/zBagAdBgJlslULlKnkvW?p=preview (When you select url1 the example is broken and you got this error : Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/ng/areq?p0=Ctrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined)

Comment: Mils, that example is very messed up. You're loading a whole app into ng-include. That's not how ng-include works. You load a small template, just a bit of code. Check out this plnk: http://plnkr.co/edit/nq1AFBaamW3xycSa98uw?p=preview it all works like you expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

`src` must evaluate to a String value, representing the URL to be included.

Still, your code is messy. You can:

1. remove `showContent` listener at all
2. remove `getView` function and leave the expression `selectedType.value`
3. `selectedType.value` must be a string, representing the URL

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/E9rH4/1/

Watch the console error (see the url it tries to fetch).

Comment: This work fine but still the same error, the problem because the url loaded use another controller...

Comment: I found a way to reproduce this probem : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/zBagAdBgJlslULlKnkvW?p=preview (When you select url1 the example is broken and you got this error : Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/ng/areq?p0=Ctrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined)

Comment: If you need to load a new **view**, and not a new **template** - you should use `ng-view` directive and `ngRoute` module, see here: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: And it is not a good idea to load a whole new page - including <html> and <body> tags.
You should reconsider the approach:
1. Use ngRoute 
2. Declare all controllers in one app module
3. Setup the routing using separate controllers and views

It will be easier and more maintainable.